# Scope ambiguity in nested if

Tags: c++, scope

Let's say one has a class Foo such as

```
class Foo {
public:
  void bar();
  operator bool() const { return true; }
};
```

then one can do

```
if(Foo foo = Foo())
{
  if(Foo foo = Foo())
  {
    foo.bar();
  }
}
```

Now I'm having trouble grasping the scope resolution going on here (I would've expected a compiler error for redeclaring foo).

I expect foo.bar() to execute on the second foo (its scope is "closer") but am I garanteed that it's actually a different object than the first foo?  Furthermore, are they each independently disposed (their destructor called) at the end of their respective if blocks?

Comment: There's no ambiguity here whatsoever.  The Standard clearly delineates the difference between *scope* and *potential scope*.  That doesn't make it a good idea, however, so DON'T DO THIS!

Comment: I meant it more as an ambiguity for me! ^^

Comment: This is called _shadowing_, and it's generally not a good idea. Although, sometimes we do it anyway: `struct s { s(int n) : n(n) { } int n; };`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ is quite happy for you to declare a variable with the same name, as long as it is inside a nested scope so there is no ambiguity.

> I expect foo.bar() to execute on the second foo (its scope is "closer")

You are correct

> but am I garanteed that it's actually a different object than the first foo?

Yes

> Furthermore, are they each independently disposed (their destructor called) at the end of their respective if blocks?

Yes

Answer (score 4):

> I expect foo.bar() to execute on the second foo (its scope is "closer")

Correct.

> but am I garanteed that it's actually a different object than the first foo?

Yes.

> Furthermore, are they each independently disposed (their destructor called) at the end of their respective if blocks?

Yes, you've got it.

Comment: @BlackBear: Why would there be?  It isn't redefinition *in the same scope*.

Comment: As Matt T has explained (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9301681/129655), C++ is okay with new variables of the same name as long as it is inside a nested scope. If it's in the same scope, then the second declaration is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The use of if statements and class object initialization in your example tends to obscure the relevant point, which is that declarations in inner scopes are perfectly legal and hide declarations of the same name in outer scopes.

A perhaps clearer example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    const int x = 10;
    std::cout << "outer x is " << x << "\n";
    {
        const double x = 12.34;
        std::cout << "    inner x is " << x << " (it hides the outer x)\n";
    }
    std::cout << "outer x is still " << x << " (inner x no longer exists)\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
outer x is 10
    inner x is 12.34 (it hides the outer x)
outer x is still 10 (inner x no longer exists)
```

Note that the inner and outer `x`s aren't even of the same type.

Though this is legal, it's usually not a good idea; the compiler has no problem with it, but it can be confusing to human readers.  If you compile with `g++ -Wshadow`, you'll get warnings:

```
c.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cpp:6:22: warning: declaration of ‘x’ shadows a previous local
c.cpp:3:15: warning: shadowed declaration is here
```