# inner loop with same variable name as outer loop

Tags: c++, nested-loops

assuming the following simple code:

```
for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  cout << "Outer i: " << i << endl;
  for(int i=0; i < 12; i++)
  {
    cout << "Inner i:" << i << endl;
  }
}
```

Works very nice. The same variable name in both loops used and the output is fine.

Do I understand it right that both variables are created on stack, and when the outer loop comes to the new inner loop, a new "namespace" (maybe the wrong name..) is created? But why is it overwritten? If I choose another name for the variable in inner loop I can also access the  `i` from outer loop.

A bit confused I am.

Comment: read a good C++ book you must

Comment: This is actually a new variable but has the same name. In different scopes, this is OK. But note that it is not possible to refer to the outer `i` from the inner loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scope ambiguity in nested if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301629/scope-ambiguity-in-nested-if)

Comment: though it works .. it is not encouraged method!

Comment: I noticed this in some other persons code and built a simple code myself to check if it compiles correctly, which it does and works. Wouldn't write such code myself but always try to understand what happens instead of just accepting what I see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Namespace" is kinda close.. but it is more about **scope**. The inner i **hides/surpresses** the outer i. You could think of another example:

```
{ 
 int i=0; //outer scope i.
 {
   int i =0; //this hides the outer scope i.. I can't use outer i here

 }
  i =1 ; //inner i is out of scope.. outer i is set to 1
}
```

Comment: I believe the term is **hides**, more than *elides*. Elides means *omit* and in the standard as far as I remember is only used to describe the suppression of copies under some circumstances.

Comment: Mmn, I would change it from elide to hide... some tutorials I read ages ago referred to it as such.

Comment: most compilers have a switch to warn about "shadowing" of variables it is generally a good idea to be warned about this. Especially if working with legacy code full of monster methods and poor practice...

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct. The code is technically valid. However, this practice has many problems and is therefore a bad idea.

Each `for` loop has a separate *scope* associated with it. The variable declared in the inner loop *shadows* the variable declared in the outer loop. There is no way to access the outer `i` from the inner loop.

Comment: I noticed this in some other persons code and built a simple code myself to check if it compiles correctly, which it does and works. Wouldn't write such code myself but always try to understand what happens instead of just accepting what I see.