# Redefinition of same variable in body after defining in for loop

Tags: c++

Here `i` is within the scope of first `for` loop, so when redefined in a nested loop, why doesn't it give a compilation error?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        cout<<"out: "<<i<<endl;
        for(float i=0; i<1; i++) {
            cout<<"in: "<<i<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler: `g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)`

Comment: Unrelated, but it's time to upgrade your compiler.

Comment: @super That's the latest compiler version in the Red Hat (at least RHEL 6) repositories. Because of this we had to use C++11 in 2020. Other repositories and custom installations were not allowed by our system administrators.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Then switch distribution. That sounds completely unacceptable.

Comment: @super RHEL was the only allowed Linux distribution because of the enterprise support and stability. We are talking about servers with > 99.999% availability. RHEL is very common on servers and all of them have GCC 4.8.5.

Comment: @ThomasSablik There's a lot of bad company policies out there. What can you do.

Comment: sometimes you cannot avoid such shadowing (psst macros), but one shouldnt do it intentionally

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Well, *that* problem has been dealt with!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inner loop with same variable name as outer loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586348/inner-loop-with-same-variable-name-as-outer-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Perfectly allowed, but can be confusing.

There are cases where you want to shadow, and there's others where you've done it inadvertently. In this case there's no reason confusion, excepting the part of using a `float` as an indexed array iterator, which is usually a bad plan.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's allowed by the language. It's usually refered to as one variable is shadowing the other.

Both gcc and clang supports `-Wshadow` flag and give you a warning for this.

Answer (score 0):

Nested variables hide the outer variables with the same name. In your example, `i` in the nested loop hides the `i` in the outer loop and it's a feature of C++. In the nested loop, whenever you use `i`, you would be using the `i` of the nested loop and there wouldn't be a way of using `i` from the outer loop without additional functions.